# KDE system unexpectedly halts and reboots

Tags: logs, kde, reboot, crash, halt

I'm having issues trying to understand why my system randomly halts or reboots. Here are the specs of my system, retrieved using neofetch:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           aeryan@aeryan-PC 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         ---------------- 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 44 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2422 (dpkg), 6 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: Plasma 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: KWin 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: breeze 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: konsole 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 13.2 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X (12) @ 3.800GHz 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 16448MiB / 32105MiB
```

I'm using this machine to run ML algorithms using TensorFlow. However, I've been monitoring CPU and GPU temperatures and it doesn't seem the system halts because of reaching a critical temperature. One thing to take into account is that my system is not upgraded to the last version (I have used the *hold* command to prevent my kernel from upgrading), since I had incompatibilities between the newer kernel versions and my code version.

I have taken a look at *syslog* for the time of the last unexpected reboot, and this is what I have found:

```
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Auth: sddm-helper crashed (exit code 15)
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 15
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Socket server stopping...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Socket server stopped.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC sddm[1192]: Display server stopping...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Session 3 of user aeryan.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Removed slice system-modprobe.slice.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: fstrim.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: logrotate.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily rotation of log files.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: man-db.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily man-db regeneration.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: motd-news.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.socket: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Unmounting /home/aeryan/Windows/D:...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Unmounting /home/aeryan/Windows/F:...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Modem Manager...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC ModemManager[1184]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC anacron[1085]: Received SIGUSR1
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC anacron[1085]: Exited
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC ModemManager[1184]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Run anacron jobs...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC ntfs-3g[1167]: Unmounting /dev/sdc1 (External Drive)
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC ntfs-3g[1167]: Permissions cache : 1 writes, 3 reads, 100.0% hits
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: Received signal 15
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC NetworkManager[1093]: <info>  [1625654503.0645] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: Socket closed.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC snapd[1122]: main.go:155: Exiting on terminated signal.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1487]: home-aeryan-Windows-F:.mount: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1123)
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC Tor[1219]: Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Simple Desktop Display Manager...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Snap Daemon...
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu core (all-snaps) system shutdown helper setup service being skipped.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: tor.service: Succeeded.
Jul  7 12:41:43 aeryan-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

I have difficulties in understanding all of the logs but, from what I've seen, it seems like the process *sddm* crashes and then *systemd* reboots my system. In other cases, my computer does not reboot but rather shutdowns incompletely. By this I mean my screen has no signal but my computer is still on (the lights, CPU, etc. are on) as if it had not completed the shutdown. Thus, I don't know if *sddm* crashing is responsible for all the reboots, shutdowns or none of them. Another possible cause could be small blackouts, but in that case I don't know if my computer would completely shutdown.

Edit:

As Daniel Kelley suggested I'm also uploading the contents of the /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/dmesg files:

**/var/log/kern.log** (around the time when the crash happened)

```
Jul  7 12:38:48 aeryan-PC kernel: [   14.574092] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
Jul  7 12:38:48 aeryan-PC kernel: [   14.689224] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Jul  7 12:38:49 aeryan-PC kernel: [   15.505398] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
Jul  7 12:38:49 aeryan-PC kernel: [   15.505502] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.0+0x77/0xa0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
Jul  7 12:38:52 aeryan-PC kernel: [   18.324043] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Jul  7 12:38:52 aeryan-PC kernel: [   18.324053] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
Jul  7 12:39:18 aeryan-PC kernel: [   43.913570] vboxdrv: Found 12 processor cores
Jul  7 12:39:18 aeryan-PC kernel: [   43.936179] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3792870341 Hz
Jul  7 12:39:18 aeryan-PC kernel: [   43.936180] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.1.16_Ubuntu (interface 0x00300000)
Jul  7 12:39:18 aeryan-PC kernel: [   43.940829] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
Jul  7 12:39:18 aeryan-PC kernel: [   43.943962] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
Jul  7 12:39:31 aeryan-PC kernel: [   57.296443] EXT4-fs (sdb5): recovery complete
Jul  7 12:39:31 aeryan-PC kernel: [   57.296446] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jul  7 12:39:31 aeryan-PC kernel: [   57.296452] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /media/aeryan/141f23da-6fba-4ad7-9f78-b5c4402a237f supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
Jul  7 12:39:32 aeryan-PC kernel: [   58.116033] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 9
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-58.64-generic 5.4.73)
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=3bd10f61-1b04-4b2b-a5b1-f8a3534b852a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009d3ff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e0ffff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009e10000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20bfff] ACPI NVS
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20c000-0x000000000affffff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000d0f40fff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d0f41000-0x00000000d0f60fff] ACPI data
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d0f61000-0x00000000d9e07fff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9e08000-0x00000000d9f4afff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9f4b000-0x00000000d9f5afff] ACPI data
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9f5b000-0x00000000da065fff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da066000-0x00000000da424fff] ACPI NVS
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da425000-0x00000000db778fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db779000-0x00000000ddffffff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000de000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000fd0fffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd500000-0x00000000fd5fffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fea00000-0x00000000fea0ffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb80000-0x00000000fec01fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec30000-0x00000000fec30fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed40000-0x00000000fed44fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedc2000-0x00000000fedcffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedd4000-0x00000000fedd5fff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000feefffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000081f37ffff] usable
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: System manufacturer System Product Name/TUF B450-PLUS GAMING, BIOS 2008 12/06/2019
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Jul  7 12:42:24 aeryan-PC kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 3792.911 MHz processor
```

**/var/log/dmesg** (first lines of the file)

```
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-58.64-generic 5.4.73)
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=3bd10f61-1b04-4b2b-a5b1-f8a3534b852a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] KERNEL supported cpus:
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021]   Intel GenuineIntel
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009d3ff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e0ffff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009e10000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20bfff] ACPI NVS
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20c000-0x000000000affffff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000d0f40fff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d0f41000-0x00000000d0f60fff] ACPI data
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d0f61000-0x00000000d9e07fff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9e08000-0x00000000d9f4afff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9f4b000-0x00000000d9f5afff] ACPI data
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9f5b000-0x00000000da065fff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da066000-0x00000000da424fff] ACPI NVS
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da425000-0x00000000db778fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db779000-0x00000000ddffffff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000de000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000fd0fffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd500000-0x00000000fd5fffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fea00000-0x00000000fea0ffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb80000-0x00000000fec01fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec30000-0x00000000fec30fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed40000-0x00000000fed44fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedc2000-0x00000000fedcffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedd4000-0x00000000fedd5fff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000feefffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000081f37ffff] usable
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[mié jul  7 12:54:58 2021] SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/kern.log` please?

Comment: @DanielKelley those files are very large and dmesg has no timestamps (at least in human readable format). Which keywords should I use to filter the files with grep?

Comment: can you run `'dmesg -T'` and upload the most recent `kern.log` file then? Need something to work with.